# Regex - select string until ' / '

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm using Regex to parse HTML (if you are reading this and doing it too, I really recommend you use [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) instead).

I have a web page the looks like this:

```
<div>&#1506;&#1489;&#1512; / Avr</div>
<div>&#1506;&#1489;/&#1512; / Av/r</div>
```

How can I select the part before the " / " (space, slash, space) and after " / "? In other words, how can I select string until " / "?

I want the it would return a list that looks like this:

```
[("&#1506;&#1489;&#1512;", "Avr"),("&#1506;&#1489;/&#1512;", "Av/r")]
```

I know I can just use:

```
regex = re.compile('<div>(.+?)</div>').findall(resp)
resp = resp.split(' / ')
```

But I want that it would done using regex.

Comment: You start out the question by telling everyone not to do what you're trying to do? Why, then, are you trying to regex parse an HTML file at all?

Comment: Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense becuase its to late for me to switch to HTMLParser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a non-capturing group to grab the part that you want with a single regex.

Change:

```
regex = re.compile('<div>(.+?)</div>').findall(resp)
```

to:

```
matches = re.compile('<div>(.+?)(?: / ).*?</div>').findall(resp)
print matches # ['&#1506;&#1489;&#1512;']
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, but, is there any way i can use if the strings in the div are on several lines? Thanks again..

Comment: @user3611091 try to use the flag `re.MULTILINE` like this: `re.compile('<div>(.+?)(?: / ).*?</div>', re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 3):

You could try the below python code.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """<div>&#1506;&#1489;&#1512; / Avr</div>
... <div>&#1506;&#1489;/&#1512; / Av/r</div>"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'^<div>(.*?) \/ ([^<]+)(?=<\/div>)', s, re.M)
>>> m
[('&#1506;&#1489;&#1512;', 'Avr'), ('&#1506;&#1489;/&#1512;', 'Av/r')]
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to extract the `Avr`

Comment: he posted `[("&#1506;&#1489;&#1512;", "Avr"),("&#1506;&#1489;/&#1512;", "Av/r")]` as expected output in his question.

Comment: hmmm... you're right! in that case your answer is better than mine! +1

Answer (score 0):

Try Beautiful Soup,Jsoup or a parer to whittle down to this but once you get to this there may still be a problem.

The negative look aheads and look behinds will do the trick. You just need to escape the "/" since it is a reserved character.

```
 re.search(".*?\/",html)
```

The look ahead is (?<=.....)

More information on the look ahead and look behind can be found at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

Also, Beautiful Soup has a method .prettify() and apache [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) can escape XML and HTML for better parsing in Jsoup. Python can encode evrything in unicode as well. There are options to get rid of tags and encodings if you have a problem there as well.

Comment: By default, GREP is greedy, and so it wil capture as much as possible before matching the single `/`. Try it on the 2nd example given.

Comment: throw a space into it .*?\s\/ or .*?\/\s or until you have letters which would be the set [A-Z]+. Grouping (.*?\s\/) should do the case.

Comment: no need. Use *non-greedy* `.*?` or a repeating non-match `[^\/]*`.

Comment: just trying to offer a bit of advice from work.see raj. he cleaned up his code and it works